# How to divide a string with delimiter in SQL Server without function

Tags: database

I was trying to divide a string:

```
t_56454sfda_343casdxf_ADBDFfdsfADSFAS_702_ASASD_fdssdAA_ffdsafAA
```

with the *underscore* delimiter. **But**, I was trying to do it without a function in T-SQL, e.g. using only:

- `substring`
- `charindex`
- `left` and `right`

to create 8 columns with data between each 'underscore'. So I could end up with the column values:

```
|   |                    |                 |     |       |         |          |
|---|--------------------|-----------------|-----|-------|---------|----------|
| t | 56454sfda343casdxf | ADBDFfdsfADSFAS | 702 | ASASD | fdssdAA | ffdsafAA |
```

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

I did that finally

```
DECLARE @temp1 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @temp2 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @temp3 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @temp4 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @temp5 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @temp6 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @temp7 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @temp8 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableName TABLE 
( 
No1 VARCHAR(100), 
No2 VARCHAR(100),
No3 VARCHAR(100),
No4 VARCHAR(100),
No5 VARCHAR(100),
No6 VARCHAR(100),
No7 VARCHAR(100),
No8 VARCHAR(100)
)
Select top 1000 @temp1 = LEFT(Column,CHARINDEX('_',Column)-1),
@temp2 = RIGHT(Column,LEN(Column)-CHARINDEX('_',Column)),
@temp3 = RIGHT(@temp2,LEN(@temp2)-CHARINDEX('_',@temp2)),
@temp4 = RIGHT(@temp3,LEN(@temp3)-CHARINDEX('_',@temp3)),
@temp5 = RIGHT(@temp4,LEN(@temp4)-CHARINDEX('_',@temp4)),
@temp6 = RIGHT(@temp5,LEN(@temp5)-CHARINDEX('_',@temp5)),
@temp7 = RIGHT(@temp6,LEN(@temp6)-CHARINDEX('_',@temp6)),
@temp8 = RIGHT(@temp7,LEN(@temp7)-CHARINDEX('_',@temp7))
FROM DB.Table (NOLOCK)
INSERT INTO @TableName(No1, No2, No3, No4, No5, No6, No7, No8) VALUES (@temp1, @temp2, @temp3,@temp4, @temp5, @temp6,@temp7, @temp8)

Update @TableName 
set No2=LEFT(No2,CHARINDEX('_',No2)-1),
No3=LEFT(No3,CHARINDEX('_',No3)-1),
No4=LEFT(No4,CHARINDEX('_',No4)-1),
No5=LEFT(No5,CHARINDEX('_',No5)-1),
No6=LEFT(No6,CHARINDEX('_',No6)-1),
No7=LEFT(No7,CHARINDEX('_',No7)-1)
Select * FROM @TableName
```

Hope someone will spend less time on this than I did.